# conflict with php zend libs and c++ libs(ctime) to build extension for php

Tags: c++, php

Im going to build an extension for PHP 5.3.x

everything is OK when I build without  vc++ lib.

```
error C2039: 'clock_t' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2873: 'clock_t' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
error C2039: 'asctime' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2873: 'asctime' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
```

and...

I include just  and got this error.
I know this problem is from my include header file in properties that required from PHP zend engine, But I do not know how solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Can you share some code? What are you including? How are you using clock_t and asctime? etc.

Answer (score 0):

change include path, e.g. to:

```
#include "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\include\time.h"
```